# Is a function in CPS required to make a tail call?

Tags: scheme, continuations, continuation-passing

I saw an example from The Scheme Programming Language, which converts

```
(letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons 'a x))]
         [g (lambda (x) (cons 'b (f x)))]
         [h (lambda (x) (g (cons 'c x)))])
  (cons 'd (h '())))   (d b a c)
```

into CPS

```
(letrec ([f (lambda (x k) (k (cons 'a x)))]
         [g (lambda (x k)
              (f x (lambda (v) (k (cons 'b v)))))]
         [h (lambda (x k) (g (cons 'c x) k))])
  (h '() (lambda (v) (cons 'd v))))
```

Besides adding an extra parameter for passing continuation to a function, is the function required to make a tail call? The example shows all the converted functions make tail calls, but the text and wikipedia for CPS don't say such a requirement explicitly.

If a function is not required to make a tail call, can we just apply the continuation to the value to be returned in the function body, i.e. if the original value to be returned is `expr`, then can we just rewrite it as `(k expr)` where `k` is the continuation parameter, without further converting it to a tail call?

For example, can `g` and `h` be rewritten as

```
g (lambda (x k) (k (cons 'b (f x (lambda (x) x)))))
h (lambda (x k) (k (g (cons 'c x) (lambda (x) x))))
```

? If it is not acceptable, I guess there might be other ways to not write them to have tail calls?

Comment: Your rewritten `g` and `h` still call `k` in tail position.

Answer (score 0):

When transforming scheme code into continuation passing style every procedure call becomes a tail call.